# MySQL Workbench join Schemas in EER Modeling

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I don't know how this happened but I was creating an EER Diagram and as I was inserting tables and creating the respective relationships between them, I noticed that Workbench was separating them apart in two different schemas. Mydb and Mydb2 with 10 and 26 tables respectively.

Now I wan't to do Forward Engineer and it is creating two different schemas in my localhost.

[image]

How can I group or join all the tables in one schema?

Answer (score 0):

mydb is the default schema created when you create a new model. Not sure about the mydb2 because new schemas use a different naming (like "new_schema1"). You can however cut and paste all objects from one schema to the other and delete the one you no longer need.